# AngularJS: All set of available controller's params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In book AngularJS from O'Reilly there is a chapter about directives. In controllers section following information:

> `controller: function controllerConstructor($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude)`
>
> This controller function is dependency injected, so the parameters listed here, while
>   potentially useful, are all optional—they can be listed in any order. **They’re also only a
>   subset of the services available.**

Were can I find all set of available services? What I'm exactly looking for is way get to require controllers inside of this controller. I.e.

```
myApp.directive('dirName',function() {
...
  require: '^parentDir',
  ...
  controller: function() {
    //which service name in function definition I should include to get to parentDir controller?
  }
```

Comment: Your questions seem to be unrelated. You're asking for a list of all Angular services, and then also how to require controllers?

Comment: In addition to Ian's comment, maybe spell out your exact problem.  It sounds like you're trying to access functions on a parent controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AngularJS, you don't inject a controller into another controller. At least, I've never seen it done.

Services are the things that you inject in Angular. They're injectable in controllers, filters, directives, and you can inject services into services.

The default services that are available for injecting are all part of the [ng core module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng) (a list of them is available in the link).

But you can also include other modules in your project and more services would become available for you.

Comment: Glad that helped. I also just remembered that you can inject providers in the config block, but that shouldn't be confusing because there's only one config block in an Angular module.